# Java: Session attribute is only in next operation

Tags: java, session, jsp, servlets

I'm posting some strings in my Session with the call

```
request.getSession().setAttribute(key, value);
```

And making the redirect with

```
response.sendRedirect(urlRedirect);
```

In almost all cases the values is there after the redirect.

But sometimes I can only read this value in the next page view, not in the redirect. There is no common behavior.

Someone has faced the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solve by changing the way of submit.

The page was submitting the data only changing the value of location.href to the Servlet Action.

We only call the submit function from the page form, and the session attributes works fine!

Answer (score 3):

Sessions are backed by a HTTP cookie. On first-time session creation, a cookie will be set in the response header. By default, cookies are bound to a specific context only.

So, if you redirect while the cookie hasn't been set yet, the session will get lost. To go around this, you need to encode the redirect URL.

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(url));
```

This appends the `jsessionid` identifier to the URL which allows the servletcontainer to locate the right session without help of a cookie.

If you don't like the `jsessionid` thing, then consider implementing a filter like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045668/jsessionid-is-occured-in-all-urls-which-are-generated-by-jstl-curl-tag/4019476#4019476) which ensures that the client is aware of the session cookie before the request enters your controller wherein you fire the redirect.

Also, if you redirect to a different context, it won't be able to access the same session. To go around this, you need to configure the servletcontainer to share the session among the contexts. In for example Tomcat, check the `emptySessionPath` attribute of the [`<Connector>` element](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) in `/conf/server.xml`.

Comment: The workarround 
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(url)); doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you verify if it is the **same** session before and after? Debug by printing/logging `session.getId()` or `${pageContext.session.id}`.

Comment: @BalusC The session is the same, I check with session.getId()

Comment: @Victor Try changing container & / | browser just to make sure

Comment: This error has never occurs on Firefox, only on IE7. And I cannot change the container...

Comment: IE is too lenient in caching. Ensure that you've an expires header which is set to 0. See the link I posted in axtavt's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Such a behaviour can be caused by caching.

If the page you are redirecting to is retrieved from the browser cache, you obviously can't see the result of `setAttribute()` on it. So make sure it's actually requested by the browser.

Comment: No, I have disabled cache for this page. :)

Comment: He has however got a point. You could in Firefox verify with Firebug *Net* panel if it is really not been requested from cache. For the right cache headers, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to do redirect through browser (response.sendRedirect()) and not on the server side (RequestDispatcher.forward())? Latter is faster as there are no network round trip.