# Remove jsessionid from wicket6/glassfish4 application

Tags: wicket, glassfish-4, wicket-1.6

I was tasked with modifying a `wicket6/glassfish4` application so that the session id changes as soon as a user logs in.  This is to avoid the problem of Session Fixation.  I used the `replaceSession()` method (from the wicket `Session` class), which does a `destroy()` and a `bind()`.  `replaceSession()`.  It seems to do the trick as the session id does indeed change. The problem is that now we see a jsessionid in the url everytime we initially log on.  The id goes away after you log in and only appears on the initial launch.

My question is, is there a way to ensure that no `jessionid` appears in the url AND that the session id changes?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possibly similar question (about JSESSIONID - not wicket) is asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045668/jsessionid-is-occured-in-all-urls-which-are-generated-by-jstl-curl-tag

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<session-config>
   <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

in your `web.xml`.

Comment: That only works if you are using servlet 3.0.  We are not there yet.

Comment: Glassfish4 should be even Servlet 3.1. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777179/how-to-find-servlet-api-version-for-glassfish-server